# Imported Entity not returned on Typeorm api

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I wrote this code to get all the ideas associated to a particular country id, but when I get the data back, it doesn't add the level and country entity I imported to the IdeaEntity. Please help

```
export class IdeaEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    @Length(7, 9)
    idea_title: string;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: LevesStatus, default: LevelsStatus.OPEN})
    levels_status: LevelsStatus;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: Payment, default: Payment.NOT_PAID })
    payment_status: Payment;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    video: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null })
    price: number

    *@ManyToOne(() => LevelsEntity, (level) => level.name, {eager: true})
    level: LevelEntity;

    *@ManyToOne(() => CountryEntity, (country) => country.country_name, {eager: true})
    country: CountryEntity;
} 



const getIdeaCountries = await IdeaRepository.createQueryBuilder('idea')
        .select()
        .where('idea.country = :query', {query: country})
        .getOne();
        console.log(getIdeaCountries?.country);
```

This is the data returned, it had no

"IdeaEntity": {
"id": "2e8541c6-e485-40c1-b0ed-bfaeb320c021",
"idea_title": "player",
"level_status": "locked",
"payment_status": "not_paid",
"video": "default.png",
"price": 50
}

Here is the level and country entity, cant figure out what I am missing there.

```
export enum Star {
    STAR = 'star',
    NO_STAR = 'N_star'
  }

export enum Green {
    GREEN = 'green',
    NO_GREEN = 'No_green'
}

@Entity("level")
// @Tree("closure-table")
export class LevelEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;


    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: Star, default: Star.NO_STAR })
    star_status: Star;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: Green, default: Green.GREEN })
    green_status: Green;
}
```

CountryEntity here

```
@Entity("country")
  export class CountryEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    @Length(7, 9)
    country_name: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    country_flag: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => FieldEntity, (field) => field.id, {eager:true})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'field_id'})
    field: FieldEntity;

    @OneToMany(() => ChallengeEntity, (challenge) => challenge.country)
    challenges: ChallengeEntity[];
}
```

Comment: can you share `LevelsEntity` and `CountryEntity` too please?

Comment: Hi @RobertRendell just added the LevelsEntity and CountryEntity.

Answer (score 1):

So it makes sense that `CountryEntity` and `LevelEntity` don't know about their related `IdeaEntity[]`, which is why you don't have a relationship to `IdeaEntity` in both of those entities.

That leads us to the question: are you just missing the join itself?

```
export class IdeaEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    @Length(7, 9)
    idea_title: string;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: LevesStatus, default: LevelsStatus.OPEN})
    levels_status: LevelsStatus;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: Payment, default: Payment.NOT_PAID })
    payment_status: Payment;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    video: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null })
    price: number

    @ManyToOne(() => LevelsEntity, (level) => level.name, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'level_id'})
    level: LevelEntity;

    @ManyToOne(() => CountryEntity, (country) => country.country_name, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'country_id'})
    country: CountryEntity;
}
```

I used this docs: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations

---

Here are the gotchas with `eager`:

> Eager relations only work when you use find* methods. If you use QueryBuilder eager relations are disabled and have to use leftJoinAndSelect to load the relation. Eager relations can only be used on one side of the relationship, using eager: true on both sides of relationship is disallowed.

Also, for completeness, here's an example of a `find*` method:

```
const questionRepository = dataSource.getRepository(Question)

// questions will be loaded with its categories
const questions = await questionRepository.find()
```